# How can i efficiently combine two css classes that has the same stats?

Tags: html, css

I have two different objects/elements/div's in my html, loader-inner and loader-inner 2. They have the exact same stats but the color, which changes with the second object. What is the most efficient way to write this code? I know I shouldn't repeat myself with unnecessary code, so can I somehow combine these two and only change the color of the second element somehow?

```
.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #4ae287;
  border: 3px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-right: 2px;
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite cubic-bezier(.83, .08, .21, .98);
  z-index: 1001;
}
.loader-inner2 {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #4ae2cb;
  border: 3px solid #f3f3f3;
  animation: loader-inner2 2s infinite cubic-bezier(.83, .08, .21, .98);
  z-index: 1001;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: @BenAdamsky That's not true. Most styles are not inherited by child elements. Besides your statement not being true, but in fact wrong and misleading, you also fail to realize that OP did not say anything about structure of his HTML, so why are you assuming it is even possible to apply either of the two classes on a child element of the other classes element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use comma and just add the selectors

```
.loader-inner, .loader-inner2 {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #4ae2cb;
  border: 3px solid #f3f3f3;
  animation: loader-inner2 2s infinite cubic-bezier(.83,.08,.21,.98);
  z-index: 1001;
}
```

Then overwrite the properties by defining a new selector

```
.loader-inner {
  border-right: 2px;
  background-color: #4ae287;
}
```

Comment: Overwriting properties is really *common* practice. And it's also really ***bad*** practice.

Comment: @connexo The question was how to get a shorter code. So it won't get shorter than that

Comment: Where do you find the word "shorter" in OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

```
.loader-inner, .loader-inner2 {
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
background-color: #4ae287;
border: 3px solid #f3f3f3;
border-right: 2px;
animation: loader-inner 2s infinite cubic-bezier(.83,.08,.21,.98);
z-index: 1001;}


.loader-inner2 {
 background-color: #4ae2cb;
}
```

Comment: Overwriting properties is really *common* practice. And it's also really ***bad*** practice.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only case you foresee I would go ahead and define them together and then create a second one to override the color like so:

```
.loader-inner, .loader-inner2 {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #4ae287;
    border: 3px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-right: 2px;
    animation: loader-inner 2s infinite cubic-bezier(.83,.08,.21,.98);
    z-index: 1001;
}

.loader-inner2 {
    background-color: #4ae2cb;
}
```

Comment: Overwriting properties is really *common* practice. And it's also really ***bad*** practice.

Answer (score 0):

Use commas to combine them:

```
.loader-inner, .loader-inner2 {
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
background-color: #4ae287;
border: 3px solid #f3f3f3;
border-right: 2px;
animation: loader-inner 2s infinite cubic-bezier(.83,.08,.21,.98);
z-index: 1001;
}
```

After that, simply overwrite the `background-color`:

```
.loader-inner2 {
background-color: #4ae2cb;
}
```

Comment: Overwriting properties is really *common* practice. And it's also really ***bad*** practice.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the cleanest way to do it:

```
.loader-inner,
.loader-inner2 {
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite cubic-bezier(.83, .08, .21, .98);
  border: 3px solid #f3f3f3;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1001;
}
.loader-inner {
  background-color: #4ae287;
  border-right-width: 2px;
}
.loader-inner2 {
  background-color: #4ae2cb;
}
```

1. Only define the properties *both have in common* in the
   **comma-separated list of selectors**.
2. Only define the *individual* properties in the **specific selectors**.